# Using Reactjs with Dexie.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dexie

I am trying to figure out how to set a react state to the value of the database. I am using [Dexie.js](http://dexie.org/).

```
var Duck = React.createClass({
getInitialState:function(){
return { century:'' }
},

fridge:function(){

var db = new Dexie('homie');
db.version(1).stores({
friends:'name, race'});

db.open().catch(function(){
alert("Open failed: ");
});

db.friends.put({name: 'Johnny', race:'hispanic'}).then(function(){
return db.friends.get('Johnny');
}).then(function(samba){
console.log(samba.race);
this.setState({century: samba.race});
});
},

render:function(){
return (<div>
<input type="submit" value="Submeet" onClick={this.fridge} />
<p>{this.state.century}</p>
</div>);
}
```

The `fridge` function works, as it places the appropriate item in the database. The only part of the code that does not work is `this.setState({century:samba.race})`. This leads to errors of `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`.

How would I re-do the `setState` to take in the data from my db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not related to Dexie.js (nice indexDB wrapper btw). You invoke `this.setState()` from a callback you pass to `.then` as handler. When the callback is invoked inside the promise context `this` is `undefined`.

To solve that you need to explicitly set the `this` of the callback, using `.bind` or the old `that = this`, or just use an arrow function ([demo](http://codepen.io/oridr22/pen/yJqBNZ)):

```
 .then((samba) => {
    console.log(samba.race);
    this.setState({
      century: samba.race
    });
  });
```